# Detecting sd card presence for web page

Tags: apache, debian, sd-card

Im working on a (web) control panel of sorts for a `fanless PC` running Debian. The device collects data into MySQL for a research study. The db tables live on an SD card. For the control panel I need to detect the presence / absence of the sd card to determine if the system is setup and running properly.

I've been working with `blkid` to get the list of attached block devices. After some searching I found the `-c /dev/null` param to avoid the cached values (if you don't do this the results are inaccurate. Removing the sd card while the system is running doesn't get reflected in the results.). This is great - when I'm running as *root*. But the web server runs as *www-data*. If I run `blkid` on this account as **blkid -c /dev/null** it doesn't return anything. Empty list. Running this command as root gives me the expected values. Same thing for **fdisk -l** (my backup plan).

Running apache2 as root isn't an option.

So I'm hunting around for suggestions to either:
1. find an accurate list of devices that I can use in php
2. figure out why these commands don't return any values when run as the apache2 account